# Show that an element has order $p$ in $S_n$ iff its cycle decomposition is a product of commuting $p$-cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, proof-verification

I would like to know if my proof below is correct.

> **Problem** Let $p$ be a prime. Show that an element has order $p$ in $S_n$ iff its cycle decomposition is a product of commuting $p$-cycles. Show by an explicit example that this need not be the case if $p$ is not prime.

I have a question here. Isn't the cycle decomposition always a composition of disjoint cycles and hence they always commute? Why does the question then say "cycle decomposition is a product of commuting"? Below is my solution and I am stuck at part $4$.

**Solution**:

1. Let $\sigma \in S_n$ have order $p$. Consider $a_1$, since $\sigma$ has order $p$, we have $\sigma^p(a_1) = a_1$. Form the cycle $C_1 = (a_1,\sigma(a_1),\sigma^2(a_1),\ldots,\sigma^{k}(a_1))$. Since $p$ is the order, we have $k \leq p$ and $k \vert p$. But $p$ is a prime and hence, $k=1$ or $k=p$. $k=1$ is a trivial case. The only other case is $k=p$. Now consider the smallest $i$ not present in $C_1$, by a similar argument, we have the cycle containing $a_i$ to be of the form $C_i = (a_i,\sigma(a_i),\sigma^2(a_i),\ldots,\sigma^{k}(a_i))$. Repeat this process and we find that any element of order $p$ in $S_n$ has its cycle decomposition as a product of commuting $p$-cycles.
2. If the cycle decomposition of $\sigma$ is a product of $p$ cycles, i.e., say $$\sigma = (a_1^{(1)},a_1^{(2)},\ldots,a_1^{(p)})(a_2^{(1)},a_2^{(2)},\ldots,a_2^{(p)})\cdots(a_k^{(1)},a_k^{(2)},\ldots,a_k^{(p)})$$where each $a_i^{(k)}$ is distinct, since the cycles in the cycle decomposition commute, we have $$\sigma^l = (a_1^{(1)},a_1^{(2)},\ldots,a_1^{(p)})^l(a_2^{(1)},a_2^{(2)},\ldots,a_2^{(p)})^l\cdots(a_k^{(1)},a_k^{(2)},\ldots,a_k^{(p)})^l = 1$$However, the order of each $p-$cycle is $p$. Hence, $p \vert l$. Hence, the minimum value of $l$ is $p$.
3. If $p$ is not a prime, consider $\sigma = (1,2)(3,4,5)$. We have the order of $\sigma$ as $6$. Even though $\sigma^6 = 1$, the two cycles in the cycle decomposition have length $3$.
4. **I am stuck here. How do I construct an example, so that if $p$ is composite, and if the cycle decomposition is a product of $p$-cycles, then the element doesn't have order $p$. This seems false.**

Comment: Yes that's right - for any $p$, a product of disjoint $p$-cycles has order $p$. But you have already answered the question in 1,2 and 3, so that's no problem!

Comment: Ok. But why does the question then say "cycle decomposition is a product of commuting"? Aren't they repeating information?

Comment: Yes I think they are! The term "cycle decompostion" generally implies that the cycles are disjoint, and hence commuting. But a product of $p$-cycles that were not disjoint might not have order $p$, so they were probably just saying for emphasis.

Comment: Your (3) is an example that shows the "iff" is not true.  There is no counterexample in the other direction: a product of (at least one) commuting $p$-cycles always has order $p$, whether $p$ is prime or not.